# ggplot graphing proportions within multiple categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph true/false proportions for data with multiple groupings.  Specifically, I want to see the true/false proportions for data column c which can be grouped by true/false data from a and b.

```
a = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50, replace=TRUE)
b = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50, replace=TRUE)
c = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50, replace=TRUE)
df = as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
```

I tried this:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = a, fill = c)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

But I don't know how to implement the true/false data from B into the graph.  Essentially I want 4 c proportions: A/B = False/False, False/True, True/False, True/True

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhtHZ.png

This is essentially the graph I want, except time=A, sex=B, and total_bill=proportion of true/false for c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(111)
a = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50, replace=TRUE)
b = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50, replace=TRUE)
c = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50, replace=TRUE)
df = as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
```

**UPDATED**

Given the comments of the OP, here is a revised version.

```
foo <- group_by(df, a, b, c) %>% 
       summarise(total = n()) %>%
       mutate(prop = total / sum(total))

# Draw a ggplot figure      
ggplot(foo, aes(x = a, y = prop, fill = b)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that is completely correct because I want the prop data to the be the data from:

foo2 = group_by(df, a, b, c) %>%
 summarise(total = n()) %>%
 mutate(prop = total / sum (total))



I want the props to be from this table where a and b are groupings (not just a)

Comment: NVM I figured it out; all I needed to do was change the group_by to include a ,c at the end and now it works perfect.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3716705 Ah glad to hear that. Why don't you post your own answer based on this? Then, I will drop this.

Comment: Nah man, you answered the question you deserve the credit (I have no idea how this site works exactly); just change your answer to include a ,c in the group_by...  specifically change it to:  group_by(df, a, b, c) %>% ....  Good stuff and thanks again!

Comment: @user3716705 Thanks for that. How did your graph come out with the code, by the way?

Comment: It worked flawlessly!  I really appreciate it; I'm just learning ggplot2 and it can be a real pain sometimes, so finding something that worked as easily as you gave me is extremely helpful.

Comment: @user3716705 Thanks for your words. I am happy to hear that you find this helpful. Given what you said, I will leave my code as it is now. :)