# ggplot + scale_size_area , how show proportions from another cat variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

After successfully plotted categorical vs categorical data

```
ggplot(data=data_big, aes(job, education)) +
  geom_count() +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 12)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1))
```

[image: cat vs cat in points]

I wish to add one dimension making those points a 'mini pie chart'. Basically I want to add info about another (binary) categorical data.

I've calculated those proportions with

```
data_big %>% group_by(job,education,y) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% mutate(rel.freq  = round(100 * n/sum(n), 2)))
```

giving a table like (incomplete tbl)

job     education   y/n q   rel.freq

```
admin. illiterate no 1 100.00
admin. basic.4y yes 10 12.99
admin. basic.4y no 67 87.01
admin. basic.6y yes 8 5.30
admin. basic.6y no 143 94.70
admin. basic.9y yes 42 8.42
admin. basic.9y no 457 91.58
admin. high.school yes 382 11.47
admin. high.school no 2947 88.53
admin. professional.course yes 49 13.50
admin. professional.course no 314 86.50
admin. university.degree yes 823 14.31
admin. university.degree no 4930 85.69
admin. unknown yes 38 15.26
admin. unknown no 211 84.74
blue-collar illiterate no 8 100.00
blue-collar basic.4y yes 123 5.31
blue-collar basic.4y no 2195 94.69
blue-collar basic.6y yes 107 7.50
blue-collar basic.6y no 1319 92.50
blue-collar basic.9y yes 240 6.62
blue-collar basic.9y no 3383 93.38
blue-collar high.school yes 94 10.71
blue-collar high.school no 784 89.29
blue-collar professional.course yes 41 9.05
blue-collar professional.course no 412 90.95
blue-collar university.degree yes 9 9.57
blue-collar university.degree no 85 90.43
blue-collar unknown yes 24 5.29
blue-collar unknown no 430 94.71
entrepreneur illiterate yes 1 50.00
entrepreneur illiterate no 1 50.00
```

How can I add the rel.freq data into my first plot ?

What I've tried :

- [Count the number of observations at each location](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_count.html)
- [Proportion by fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264993/ggplot-graphing-proportions-within-multiple-categories)

but somehow it explains how to show proportion based on one of the 'initial' categories, and not a 3rd one.

Edit : After exchanging with @Nathan who pointed me towards a better direction, i managed to get to this :

[final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Qz3.png)

Comment: I don't know how you can do mini pie charts, but would using fill aesthetic be acceptable?

Comment: @NathanDay yes, the goal is to show proportions of this 3rd binary variable

Comment: `geom_scatterpie()`? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterpie/vignettes/scatterpie.html (many kittens will die if you do this tho :-)

Answer (score 1):

just leave `geom_count` behind and do what it was doing with a new column:

```
# added a few new rows for multiple jobs
job     education   y/n q   rel.freq
admin.  illiterate  no  1   100.00
admin.  basic.4y    yes 10  12.99
admin.  basic.4y    no  67  87.01
admin.  basic.6y    yes 8   5.30
admin.  basic.6y    no  143 94.70
admin.  basic.9y    yes 42  8.42
tech    basic.9y    no  22  10
tech    basic.4y    no  58  50
```

maybe you want `sum(q)` here instead:

```
# this is all geom_count really does but it's ornery with aes(fill)
data_big <- data_big %>% group_by(education, job) %>% mutate(cnt = sum(q))

# color for effect
ggplot(data=data_big, aes(job, education)) +
    geom_point(aes(size = cnt, fill = rel.freq),shape = 21) +
    scale_size_area(max_size = 12, name = "Count")+
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu", name = "Rel.Freq") +
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1))
```

[image]

or you could take advantage of faceting to display `data_big$y/n` like this :

```
data_big <- data_big %>% group_by(education, job, `y/n`) %>% mutate(cnt = sum(q))

ggplot(data=data_big, aes(job, education)) +
    geom_point(aes(size = cnt, fill = rel.freq),shape = 21) +
    scale_size_area(max_size = 12, name = "Count")+
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu", name = "Rel.Freq") +
    theme_bw()+
    facet_wrap(~`y/n`) +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Nathan Day and thx. The count seems odd 
1) admin + basic.4y has a count total of 77
2) admin + basic.6y has a count total of 151

Comment: Hey @Nathan Day and thx. The count seems odd 
1.  admin + basic.4y has a count total of 77
2.  admin + basic.6y has a count total of 151

but here the area is the same (and labels point to much lower values)

Comment: updated using `sum(q)` however hrbrmstr's comment could be a more promising solution for you going forward

Comment: Thanks for you initial response, i've managed to get to a suitable answer. 
What I did was ,as you, taking a sum(q). BUT the problem is that there was 2 lines for each (job vs education) , one for yes and one for no.
Luckily, i can filter the table, taking only the lines with Y (because of binarity, one line have the info of the other ;)

Comment: facetting could be useful too

Comment: but then, the color palette make no sens. And you (reader) get lost in the variability of q observations  rather than the y/n proportions

Comment: I've added final version on original post